# Could Factory pattern be a generic Singleton?

Tags: php, singleton, overloading, factory

Isn't factory a general singleton? Or may the Factory pattern be Singleton sometimes?
Let's assume we have the following Factory pattern class:

```
abstract class Factory {

    /* This cache contains objects that has already been called.
    ** It stores the class name, arguments and the object itself.
    ** If an another call for the same class with the same arguments 
    ** is made we return the object.
    */ 
    private static $cache;

    public static function __callStatic($class, $args) {
        // 1) we check if the class already exists in the cache

            // 2) if it does then we return the object in the cache

            // 3.1) otherwise we create a new object
            // 3.2) we pass to the constructor of that object the arguments with ReflectionClass
            // 3.3) we store the class name, arguments and object in the cache
    }

}
```

And a concrete class

```
class My extends Factory {}
```

And let's assume we have a class `DontKnow($arg1, $arg2)` that accept arguments `$arg1` and `$arg2` to the constructor. And let's assume we have another class `DoNot()` that doesn't accept any parameter to the constructor.

Now when we call

```
My::DontKnow('sample', 3);
```

we return an object that is now stored inside the cache of our factory class. 
If we call it again our factory class will not instantiate a new object, but will use the same again.

So for example if we set `My::DontKnow('sample', 3)->setSomething('key', 'myvalue');` and inside another scope we call  `My::DontKnow('sample', 3)->getSomething('key');` it will print `myvalue`.

But if we call `My::DoNot()` the factory class will return a "singleton" object of the class DoNot() that, since our factory class `My` is static, has static scope and can be, then, called everywhere.

Isn't this another example of Singleton? Is this to avoid as well as the Singleton pattern?

Comment: A Factory does not necessarily, or even typically, cache the objects it creates, nor are factories typically called statically. What you describe is a Registry or Singleton, not a Factory.

Comment: @deceze, but this is a factory class. It produce objects, just statically. It's true, it's not necessary to do that. But it could happen. This is not a Singleton. It has nothing to do with Singletons apart from the fact that it is static.

Comment: Just because you *call* it `Factory` doesn't mean it is one. :) What you have is a static Singleton Registry Factory Service Locator, not just a simple factory.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you call it. But what are you trying to achieve that is much more important. Does it do what it should? Does it encapsulate? Is it loose coupling etc. @deceze excellent answer! +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. What you are describing would be a special use case of the factory pattern or not a factory at all. A simple factory doesn't do 'instance management', it just returns a new instance of the needed concrete subclass.

The fact that the factory method itself is static, doesn't mean that the methods of the returned subclass are. A factory, as the name says it, produces concrete objects with non-static functionality.

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method

Comment: Ok, should this be avoided or can I use it?

Comment: This static Singleton Registry Factory Service Locator of yours? I don't know, it depends... I think you should rather not if you can avoid it. Does it make unit testing more difficult? YES.